# Using Raspberry Pi Zero W connected to LM7805 or dc buck converter from UPS LEAD acid battery

Tags: pi-zero-w, battery, ups

Planning to build battery backup for raspberry pi zero w that last for days from 12v lead acid PC ups battery.

**Parts**

PC UPS, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ur-D37-juo

LM7805, https://www.ebay.in/itm/263163136739?aff_source=hcurve

DC to DC Buck convertor, https://www.ebay.in/itm/6-24V-12V-24V-to-5V-3A-CAR-USB-Charger-Module-DC-Buck-step-down-Converter/182672596411?hash=item2a88229dbb:g:BB8AAOSw5cNYcEeC

**Setup**

PC UPS 12v Lead acid battery->LM7805->Raspberry Pi zero micro usb.

Questions

Any chance for a problem while charging PC ups? Will it overload/overheat LM7805?

12v DC to 5v DC USB buck converter vs LM7805. Which one is better for pi zero?

Is it possible to use another LM7805 from the 12v battery parallel to run another raspberry pi zero?

Comment: it is unclear what your question is.. A linear regulator is a poor choice.. 70% of your power will be converted to heat and you will need a large heatsink.

Comment: This isn't really a Pi specific question.  You could be powering any similar device.  I'd use the most efficient converter so there is less wasted heat.  That is probably going to be the buck converter.

Comment: if you have an existing UPS why not just plug a regular PI power supply into it.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I think regular PI power supply will drain ups bettery power faster. Want to use pi in battery for minimum of 2 days.

Comment: @joan Thanks, Heating is really a concern. I'll try with buck converter.

Comment: @Milliways I never seen anyone used a PC UPS to run raspberry pi. One ebay seller suggested to use linear regular(not sure how much he really know about this). Thanks for the details about the efficiency of linear regulator. Will try with buck converter. Can I use two buck converters from 12v source? Is there a chance for burning buck converter or pi while lead acid battery charging?

Comment: Better to ask in "SE Electrical Engineering"

Comment: Complete buck regulators packaged like a discrete component are common.  For example, I have used https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/murata-power-solutions-inc/OKR-T-1.5-W12-C/811-2782-ND/3674288 to power an RPI from a 12V source.

Comment: @crj11 Thanks for the digikey link, will try out this one .

Comment: If you are using USB peripherals that have significant current requirements, you might need to use one with higher current.  I have used the linked part with a PI 3 with minimal (~200ma) USB power draw.  Don't forget the 267 ohm resistor  to set the output voltage.